# Evitar rerender de child components cuando las props del padre cambian

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Tengo un componente que, en una parte, renderiza otro componente hijo.
Quiero que ese componente hijo no se rerenderice a menos que cambie una prop que el padre le pase.
usé useMemo, luego investigué y leí que useMemo no retorna componentes en su función sino valores, y encontré que se podía usar react.memo, pero en la documentación indica explicitamente que NO debe usarse con el objetivo de evitar re renders porque podría causar bugs.
La pregunta es, hay algo similar al shouldComponentUpdate que pueda tener el child component? Gracias!

El código sería algo similar a esto:

```
const FatherComponent = ({sayHi}) => {


return (
     <> 
    {sayHi ? 'Hi' : 'Bye'}
    ...
    <ChildComponent property={foo} />
    </>
}
```

**sayHi** es una property que viene de otro componente
**foo** es la property que se le pasa al *ChildComponent*
Yo solo quiero que el *childComponent* se re renderice solamente si **foo** cambia, sin embargo, cada vez que **sayHi** cambia, el childComponent se re renderiza nuevamente.

Agradezco la ayuda!

Nota al pie: con useMemo en el FatherComponent funciona, pero no es buena practica

```
const child = useMemo(()=> {
    return <ChildComponent property={foo} />
},[foo]}
```

Comment: Probaste con useEffect?

Comment: Pero useEffect() hace que una función se ejecute cuando las dependencias cambias, en mi caso no quiero q se ejecute una función sino q se renderice un compo sólo cuando una prop cambie.
Me quedé con useMemo, funciona bien jeje.

Comment: Genial que te funcionó! Solo como referencia, useEffect cumple las funciones del montaje y la actualización del componente mediante el cambio de estado de alguna variable, ejecutándose solo una vez o ejecutando en cada interacción con el aplicativo, eso lo decides tú mediante el segundo parámetro solicitado 

Comment: @robertodevetaks, puedes responder tu propia pregunta, ¿Cual es tu caso de uso? ¿Qué tan costosa es la computación del componente al cual quieres aplicar `useMemo`? Saludos

Comment: Una aclaración sobre useMemo, es correcto utilizarlo cuando queremos optimizar la aplicación, pero esta mal si dependemos del useMemo para que la aplicación funcione de la manera esperada. Es decir, más alla de los re-renders, la aplicación debería funcionar tanto con el useMemo, como sin él. La pregunta es, porque queres evitar el re-render de dicho componente? Como afecta este comportamiento al resto de tu aplicación?

Comment: Modifique mi respuesta anterior, pues recién estuve estudiando más a fondo el tema de re-render innecesario de componentes.

Answer (score 0):

#### Evitar re-render innecesarios de functional components

Al parecer no hay forma de emular `ShouldComponentUpdate` para functional components, aunque hay formas de evitar el re-render de un `functional component`.

Si es verdad que hay advertencias del equipo de reactJS con respecto al uso de [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) y [memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) para evitar re-renders innecesarios:

> Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.

> You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee.

Aunque por otro lado, mencionan que pueden usarse para mejorar el performance de la App.

---

Aquí dejo la forma de evitar el re-render del componente `ChildComponent` con el método `memo` para que quede documentado:

```
const FatherComponent = ({sayHi}) => {
  const [foo, setfoo] = useState("hola foo");
  
  /*Esto tambíen evita el re-render
    const child = useMemo(()=> {
    return <ChildComponent property={foo} />
  },[foo]);*/

  return (
       <> 
      {sayHi ? 'Hi' : 'Bye'}
      <ChildComponentMemo property={foo} />
      </>
  )
}
//Stateless:Solo recibe props
function ChildComponent(props){
  return <p>in child {props.property}</p>
}

const ChildComponentMemo = memo(ChildComponent);
```

Me quedo con dudas, como por ejemplo cuales son esos bugs que se mencionan, además cual es la diferencia entre usar `memo` y `useMemo` para evitar re-render innecesarios, ya que ambos parecen funcionar igual.

Con `memo` se puede realizar una comparación de `props` controlada, esa puede ser una diferencia que nos ayude a decidir cual método nos conviene elegir.

Otra opcíón es transfromar el `functional component` a `class` como `PureComponent`, que es una forma oficial de evitar el re-render innecesario de `Components`.

Al menos ya sabemos que, si hay algún componente que presenta problemas de rendimiento, usar `memo`, `useMemo` o `PureComponent` debe ser la opción a elegir para **optimizar nuestra app**.

[Liga de interes](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#avoid-reconciliation)

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente se hace condicional con el componente esta permitido en jsx.
Trata de envolver con un div todo se tiene que devolver algo o null, parece el echo de que no esta todo envuelto en un div puede ser la causa de ese bug, por que no deberias tener problema.
En el ejemplo sayHai es booleano se renderiza en base a condicionales:

```
const FatherComponent = (props) => {


return (
  <div>
      {props.sayHai ? 'hai','bye'}
      <ChildComponent property={foo} /> 
  </div>
 )

}
```

Si no usa un PureComponent :

```
class ChildComponent extends React.PureComponent {

    shouldComponentUpdate(oldProps, newProps, oldState, newState) {
       return oldProps.foo !== newProps.foo
     }
    render(){
      ....
     }

}
```